# Python discord bot with discord.py goes offline after a few minutes

Tags: python

```
import praw
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

# api connection
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='',
                     client_secret='',
                     username='',
                     password='',
                     user_agent='')

subr = reddit.subreddit('GameDeals')
TOKEN = 'token'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

async def my_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channel = client.get_channel(685548148910719207)
    for post in subr.stream.submissions():
        submission = post.selftext
        if len(submission) < 2000:
            if '|' in submission:
                await channel.send(submission)
                await asyncio.sleep(2)

client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
client.run(TOKEN)
```

The program runs through the background process and posts the messages but then after a couple minutes the bot goes offline while the python script keeps running